# Screen compatibility and repeat play button

Tags: javascript, html, css

These are my codes: I have an error in the code.. The first: When the window is minimized, the screen is not compatible (the font is large and the image is small)
The second error: when pressing the play button. The sound is played once
I want it to work every time I press the button.. not once.. and when I press the play button I want the stop sound button to appear and so on

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjiWo.jpg)

[enter link description here][2]

```js
let counter = 0;
const mysong = document.getElementById("mysong"),
  icon = document.getElementById("icon"),
  words = [...document.querySelectorAll(".word", ".wordw")],
  speed = 550,
  setColor = () => {
    words[counter].style.color = "#29b4af";
    words.map((word, index) => {
      if (index !== counter) {
        word.style.color = "initial";
      }
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (counter < words.length)
        setColor();
      else
        words.forEach(el => el.style.color = 'initial');
      counter++;
    }, speed);
  };
icon.onclick = () => {
  setColor();
  mysong.play();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("../imgg/1.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 10% 10%;
  background-position: top;
  background-size: 32.7%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.sayfa1 {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)translateY(-50%);
}

.second {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 190%;
  right: -25%;
  transform: translateX(-65%)translateY(-65%);
}

.third {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 240%;
  right: -20%;
  transform: translateX(-65%)translateY(-65%);
}

.but1 {
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%)translateY(-50%);
}

.word {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.previous {
  background-color: #29b4af;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.next {
  background-color: #29b4af;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.start {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
  size: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.starbut {
  border-radius: 8px;
  top: 90%;
  left: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%)translateY(-50%);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

#icon {
  width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="sayfa1">

  <h1>
    <span class="word">Hi</span>
    <span class="word">welcome</span>
    <span class="word">back</span></h1>
</div>

<div class="but1">
  <a href="2.html" class="previous"> previous </a>
  <a href="#" class="start" id="icon">&#9835;</a>
</div>

<audio id="mysong">
        <source src="imgg/bhika.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
      </audio>
```

New:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjiWo.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It should resolve errors

HTML file

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>حكاية حرف الباء </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta thhp-rquiv="x-UA-compatile" content="IE=edge,cheome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scsle=1.0">
</head>
<style>
     body {
        background-image: url("zdj.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    background-size: 493px 829px;
    }
</style>
........
```

Javascript file

```
let counter = 0;
let playsSong = false;
let timeoutId = null;

const mysong = document.getElementById("mysong"),
    icon = document.getElementById("icon"),
    words = [...document.querySelectorAll(".word", ".wordw")],
    speed = 550,
    setColor = () => {
        playsSong = true;
        words[counter].style.color = "#29b4af";

        words.map((word, index) => {
            if (index !== counter) {
                word.style.color = "initial";
            }
        });

        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            if (counter < words.length) setColor();
            else words.forEach((el) => (el.style.color = "initial"));

            if (counter == words.length) {
                counter = 0;
                playsSong = false;
                return;
            }

            counter++;
        }, speed);
    },
    stopColor = () => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        playsSong = false;
    };

icon.onclick = () => {
    if (!playsSong) {
        setColor();
        mysong.play();
    } else {
        stopColor();
        mysong.pause();
    }
};
```

Comment: thank u very much sir , The play button works .. but at the end of the sound it cuts off when the sound is restarted, the erased part comes from the end of the sound .. I add the photo for first error

Comment: Attach picture and mp3 file.

Comment: I added audio and video to the question sir

Comment: @AmnaChegg check update

Comment: Thank you sir , the botun is perfect and works 100%.. but in the picture: I want it to be compatible with the screen when the window is minimized and also compatible with the mobile screen or iPad..

Comment: When I published the link and opened it from the mobile, it was like this (look at the question, I added a second picture). I hope you understand my point, sir.

Comment: @AmnaChegg check update

Comment: sir It is compatible with the mobile screen now.. but the image appears large on the windows window..
I want the image to correspond to the Google window on the computer and also to the mobile screen at the same time

Comment: I add ( Last photo after update  in the Q )It appears like this in the google windows PC

Comment: @AmnaChegg now it's ok?

Comment: The picture is now complete.. but the text is not in place .. I added a picture in the Q

Comment: @Amnamirza its different image. Send me maybe url to netlify site and I will look at this but morning. If it's all image and text must be in the cloud its impossible. Then you should also add text in image. I dont want add more comments so if you need any more help than that here is my discord: Lukas442#5336

Comment: I added you .. https://bright-pithivier-82a780.netlify.app